# How to set custom height for md-grid-tile in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Grid from Angular Material.

How to set custom height for `md-grid-tile` in Angular Material? I need to do this only for some fields in collection.

I tried to do this using CSS style and to set as `height="100px"`.

Comment: If you have other tiles in the column, you can set it with proportionally using `rowSpan` -- from the [Material API.](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/api) You could add another transparent tile to the column to make this work with a single tile.

Comment: You mean to add `rowSpan` in object?

Comment: I've always bound this in the template, i.e. `<md-grid-tile [rowspan] = "variableRowspan">`

Comment: How to set height for `[rowspan]`?

Comment: It's a integer proportion, so if you have 2 tiles in your column with the first set to 1 and the second 2, the first will be 33% of the parent height and the second 66%. This will be dynamic, so if you're explicitly looking for a fixed pixel height you'll have to find another way.

Comment: I need to set height for header manually

Comment: Or it should be 1/2 of another fields

Comment: If it needs to be half of another tile, you can set both tiles to a `rowSpan` of 1 and `md-grid-list` will make them both 50% if they're in the same column.

Comment: can you write example please

Comment: I tried this ` <md-grid-tile class="header" rowSpan="1">`

Comment: When you say "set custom height for `md-grid-tile`", do you mean changing the height of the actual tile or changing the height of contents inside the tile?

Comment: Yes, you re right